# Shrinking NTFS drives (in virtual machines)

Tags: virtual-machine, ntfs, metadata

Sometimes it’s useful to shrink the drive image of a VM to reduce wasted space on the host. We do this by defragmenting and compacting the contents of the virtual drive, wiping the free space, then defragmenting the free space so that it is all at the end.

This works pretty well with a FAT32 drive, but NTFS drives have metadata files that are usually located somewhere in the middle of the drive, so the resulting drive image often ends up being about 1/3 larger than it needs to be, because half of the free space is stuck between the data and the metadata.

Figure 1 shows a few hundred megabytes of free space being added to the drive image (`.vmdk` file) because of NTFS metadata files.

Depending on the software and file-formats, this can be reduce (or possibly even eliminated?), but in my experience, NTFS metadata prevents a drive image file from being shrunk as much as it can be.

Does anybody have any tips on compensating for NTFS metadata files and reducing the drive image of an NTFS drive as much as possible?

**Figure 1**: Screenshot of Defraggler showing NTFS drive with free space defragged, but split due to NTFS metadata files

[image: Screenshot of Defraggler showing NTFS drive with free space defragged, but split due to NTFS metadata files]

Comment: Have you tried cloning the drive to another, virgin VM?

Comment: @ernie, no but I don’t see how that could help because NTFS volumes always put some of their metadata files (e.g., the mirror MFT) in the middle.

Comment: Shrinking a NTFS within a virtual machine is no different then shrinking a NTFS parition on an actual machine.  The only additional step is using the virtual machine software to shrink the actual file, after you have adjusted the size of the partition, in the operating system.  Try doing a defrag before you boot into Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound, you’ve missed the point, I can already defrag the drive and  all, the problem is that NTFS volumes stick some metadata files in the **middle** of the volume which divides the free space into two sections, so the drive-image on the host cannot be reduce to encompass only the actual data and exclude the free space because there is a metadata file in the middle which causes the drive-image file to include a large chunk of free space. I hope that makes it clear enough.